# Get current index of jCarouselLite image/page

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, jcarousellite

I've looked through the other questions about this and not found a suitable answer.

What I need is very simple: The index of the currently shown item.

Here's my little chunk of config

```
    $('.carousel').jCarouselLite(
    { 
        btnNext: "#right-navigation",
        btnPrev: "#left-navigation",
        visible: 1,
        afterEnd: function(a)
        {
            // Code that requires the index
        }
    });
```

Note: the `a` is an object

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The elements representing the items
>   that are visible after the animation
>   ends are passed in as argument.

so you should be able to do something like

```
afterEnd: function(a){
   var index = $(a[0]).index();
}
```

to get the index of the first element